# Passing information using post method without session variables

Tags: php

I will admit immediately that this is homework. I am only here as a last resort after I cannot find a suitable answer elsewhere. My assignment is having me pass information between posts without using a session variable or cookies in php. Essentially as the user continues to guess a hidden variable carries over all the past guesses up to that point. I am trying to build a string variable that holds them all and then assign it to the post variable but I cannot get anything to read off of the guessCounter variable i either get an undefined index error at the line of code that should be adding to my string variable or im just not getting anything passed over at all. here is my code any help would be greatly appreciated as I have been at this for awhile now.

```
  <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['playerGuess'])) {
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($_POST) ;  echo "</pre>";
    }
    ?>
    <?php
    $wordChoices = array("grape", "apple", "orange", "banana", "plum", "grapefruit");
    $textToPlayer = "<font color = 'red'>It's time to play the guessing game!(1)</font>";
    $theRightAnswer= array_rand($wordChoices, 1);
    $passItOn = " ";
    $_POST['guessCounter']=$passItOn;
    $guessTestTracker = $_POST['guessCounter'];
    $_POST['theAnswer'] = $theRightAnswer;
    if(isset($_POST['playerGuess'])) {
    $passItOn = $_POST['playerGuess'];
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {
        $guessTestTracker = $_GET['guessCounter'];

        $theRightAnswer = $_GET['theAnswer'];
    }
    else if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        if(isset($_POST['playerGuess'])) {
            if(empty($_POST['playerGuess'])) {
                $textToPlayer = "<font color = 'red'>Come on, enter something(2)</font>";
            }
            else if(in_array($_POST['playerGuess'],$wordChoices)==false) {
                $textToPlayer = "<font color = 'red'>Hey, that's not even a valid guess. Try again (5)</font>";
                $passItOn = $_POST['guessCounter'].$passItOn;
            }
            if(in_array($_POST['playerGuess'],$wordChoices)&&$_POST['playerGuess']!=$wordChoices[$theRightAnswer]) {
                $textToPlayer = "<font color = 'red'>Sorry ".$_POST['playerGuess']." is wrong. Try again(4)</font>";
                $passItOn = $_POST['guessCounter'].$passItOn;
            }
            if($_POST['playerGuess']==$wordChoices[$theRightAnswer]) {
                $textToPlayer = "<font color = 'red'>You guessed ".$_POST['playerGuess']." and that's CORRECT!!!(3)</font>";
                $passItOn = $_POST['guessCounter'].$passItOn;

            }
        }
    }
}
$_POST['guessCounter'] = $passItOn;
$theRightAnswer=$_POST['theAnswer'];

for($i=0;$i<count($wordChoices);$i++){
    if($i==$theRightAnswer) {
        echo "<font color = 'green'>$wordChoices[$i]</font>";
    }
    else {
    echo $wordChoices[$i];
    }
    if($i != count($wordChoices) - 1) {
        echo " | ";
        }
    }
 ?>
<h1>Word Guess</h1>
<a href ="">Refresh this page</a>
<h3>Guess the word I'm thinking</h3>
<form action ="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method = "post">
<input type = "text" name = "playerGuess" size = 20>
<input type = "hidden" name = "guessCounter" value = "<?php echo $guessTestTracker; ?>">
<input type = "hidden" name = "theAnswer" value = "<?php echo $theRightAnswer; ?>">
<input type = "submit" value="GUESS" name = "submitButton">
</form>

<?php 


    echo $textToPlayer;
    echo $theRightAnswer;
    echo $guessTestTracker;



?>
```

Comment: Are you allowed to use cookies?

Comment: no cookies either, should have added that in the main question

Comment: Why do you have `$passItOn = $_GET['guessCounter'].$passItOn;` in conoditial for POST data?

Comment: I forgot to change that back to POST , as I mentioned in the main question I have ran out of ideas and tried pretty much anything and everything.

Comment: Why can't you use hidden variables or pass data from one form to other using ajax and pass data from js to new form?

Comment: i am using hidden variables my problem is building the hidden variable up to contain all past guesses. ajax and js are not an optiion either as they are not allowed

Comment: @NateGreene I agree with cartina. Just write the calculated values into hidden fields, then they will be available in POST data for succeding submissions. Read the current submission and add it to array, write the serialized array to a hidden field. On ne t submission unserialize the submitted array and add the current submission to it. Repeat ad infinitum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a minimal functional example of what  you need to do. There are still a couple of minor bugs (like duplicate entries in the history), but I've left these as an exercise for you. Treat this as a starting point and build up what you need from it.

I've added comments to explain what's happening, so hopefully it is clear to you.

```
$answer = null;
$history = [];
$choices = ['apple', 'grape', 'banana'];
$message = '';

// check if a guess has been made.
if (!empty($_POST) && !empty($_POST['guess'])) {
    // check if previous guesses have been made.
    if (!empty($_POST['history'])) {
        $history = explode(',', $_POST['history']);
    }

    // check guess.
    if (!empty($_POST['answer']) && !empty($_POST['guess'])) {
        // check guess and answer are both valid.
        if (in_array($_POST['guess'], $choices) && isset($choices[$_POST['answer']])) {
            if ($_POST['guess'] == $choices[$_POST['answer']]) {
                // correct; clear history.
                $history = [];
                $message = 'correct!';
            } else {
                // incorrect; add to history and set previous answer to current.
                $history[] = $_POST['guess'];
                $answer = $_POST['answer'];
                $message = 'incorrect!';
            }
        } else {
            // invalid choice or answer value.
        }
    }
}

if (empty($answer)) {
    // no answer set yet (new page load or correct guess); create new answer.
    $answer = rand(0, count($choices) - 1);
}

?>
<p>Guess the word I'm thinking:</p>
<p><?php echo implode(' | ', $choices) ?></p>
<form method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="history" value="<?php echo implode(',', $history); ?>">
    <input type="text" name="guess">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Guess">
</form>
<p><?php echo $message; ?></p>
```

Comment: Thanks that really cleared things up for me as to how you are supposed to use explode/implode

Comment: You're welcome, @NateGreene. Please remember to accept the answer so that people with a similar question in the future will know what worked for you.